# Is there a way to create a database with a hash table that features constant time lookup?

Tags: c++, database, function, hashtable

I'm trying to create a database in my program with a hash table for constant time lookups. Right now I have the hash table coded, and I have a few stored values in the table(I used an array of structures). But I wanted to enable the user of my code to manually input a new value and permanently store it in a table. I figured I might need to use a database as I don't think implementing a text file would allow the constant time look-ups the hashtable provides. I also don't know how to implement an array of structures in a text file if that would be the better option. Any help?

EDIT: I didn't make this clear enough, but is it possible for me to make a hash table and have the values I input in the hash table permanently stored un the table for constant time look-up? Or do I have to manually code in everything?

Comment: I hope your hash function is not too collision prone.

Comment: Is your question about constant time lookup or how to serialize that data structure to disk? It's two different questions.

Comment: @JesperJuhl my hash function is near collision proof. The original array has 26 buckets for the first letter in the inputted item. Then the value inside each bucket is an array with 100 buckets each and the key being determined by the value of the middle and last character, with a special formula to make each input unique.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I want to have a hash table where I can input my values and have them stored in the hash table. Hash tables are already near constant time look up.

Comment: What is your specific programming question?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I want to know if it's possible for me to create a hash table and have values I input be permanently stored in the table, or if I have to manually code in every value of the hash table?

Comment: A hash table is a data structure. It doesn't say anything about if it's stored permanently or not. Yes, you can store data permanently in a hash table. I don't understand _"or if I have to manually code in every value of the hash table"_

Comment: _"I figured I might need to use a database as I don't think implementing a text file would allow the constant time look-ups the hashtable provides."_  Databases can also use memory or files to store the data, e.g. SQLite. Why do you think a hash table is not possible with a text file?

Comment: The question is still unclear for me. Is it possible that you don't have a concrete question but just want to discuss about this topic?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I don't have a concrete understanding of hash tables, but I do know that a hash key will be required for constant time look up. How will this key be implemented in a text file? Unless you can search in constant time in a text file?

Comment: What is the difference between memory and a hard drive? You know the start position and an offset. Moving the cursor in a file to a position is O(1). It's identical to hash maps in memory. You can use the filesystem structure for linked lists in each bucket. You don't search in the file. You calculate the exact position using the hash.

Answer (score 1):

There are many third party libraries you can use for this. They are mostly C libraries, which can be used in C++.

If you are on a typical Linux platform, you probably already have [gdbm](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) installed, so you might as well just use that.

Other options include [LMDB](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/index.html), [qdbm](https://dbmx.net/qdbm/index.html), and BerkeleyDB, to name just a very few.

edit: Oops, don't know how I forgot [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb), from the big G.